# Webpack 4 externals, unexpected token, load external library

Tags: webpack

I'm getting that error unexpected token when I try to use this config:

```
externals: {
  autocapture: [
    'http://some-cdn.example.com/library.js',
    'autocapture', // or maybe 'TICautocapture'?
    'TICautocapture',
  ],
}
```

And also, when I try to add the `externalsType` option I got an:
 `configuration has an unknown property 'externalsType'.`

So how should I config `webpack` in order to have that external loaded?

Comment: You might be using a new feature from webpack 5. Here's the documentation for webpack 4 https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/.

Comment: Thanks. FInally I solved this by another way, had to append the library to the DOM in a script element, then use it from `window.`